# How to pass URI parameters in Dredd

Tags: dredd

I'm new to Dredd and wanted to run the uber.yaml found [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/examples/v2.0/yaml/uber.yaml). However, I keep running into the following error(s):

```
info: Configuration './dredd.yml' found, ignoring other arguments.
error: Compilation error in file 'uber.yaml': Required URI parameter 'latitude' 
has no example or default value. (Products > /v1/products > Product Types)
```

Not sure how to get past these, wasn't able to find what I was looking for using the Dredd documentation. Any help woudl be grealy appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, was able to find an answer had to add x-example in the swagger.yaml.